# Dynamically populate an array based on amount of data

Tags: javascript

I have a bar chart that has an unknown amount of data but I want to iterate through 3 background colours and assign each one to an array of bgcolours dependent on the amount of data. An example of what I have done so far is:

```
var variableLengthColoursList = [];
var colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    variableLengthColoursList.push(colours[i]);
}
```

However, if there is 4 lots of data the final bar in chart will not have a background colour.
Sorry about the title I am not sure what to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) (or mod/modulo/modulus operator) can help with this.

You don't necessarily want the color at the position of `i` in the array, since as you say that can extend beyond the bounds of that array.  Instead, you want the color at the position of `i % colours.length` as that would be the remainder of dividing `i` by `colours.length`, which for any incrementing `i` would simply repeat the indexes of `colours`:

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var variableLengthColoursList = [];
var colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    variableLengthColoursList.push(colours[i % colours.length]);
}
console.log(variableLengthColoursList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically generate a color.

This way you have infinite number of possible colors

Check this:

```js
const data = ['data 1','data 2','data 3','data 4','data 5','data 6','data 8','data 9'];
function generateColor(){
  const color = () => Math.round(Math.random()*255).toString(16).padStart(2,'0');
  return `#${color()}${color()}${color()}`;
}
data.forEach(d => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.backgroundColor = generateColor();
  div.innerText = d;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but some of your colours are very close to each other

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes not.. it is random colors. If its important always possible to add check and reganarate color of need